# Child view border overrides parent's one on react-native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, styles

I have child `View` inside a Parent `View` component. I set Parent's border but child View's border override parent's one.

Here is the screen

[image]

Here is my code

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row',marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20, height: height/20,
                    width: width-40, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 4, borderColor: '#D3D3D3'}}>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',flexDirection: 'row',
                        height: height/20, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                      <Thumbnail style={{marginLeft: 5,width: 20, height: 20}} square source={require('../assets/Turkey.png')}/>
                      <Picker mode="dropdown" selectedValue={this.state.selectedCountry}
                              onValueChange={(value)=>this.onCodeChanged(value)}
                              >
                          <Picker.Item label="+44" value="England"></Picker.Item>
                          <Picker.Item label="+90" value="Turkey"></Picker.Item>
                      </Picker>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{height: height/20, width: 250}}>
                        <Input placeholder="Phone" placeholderTextColor='#D3D3D3'/>
                    </View>
                </View>
```

I tried to set `borderBottomWidth` props of child view to 0, but it did not work. Anyone know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Is not the border. You are putting the height of everything (height/20) but you are not taking into account the border you just added, which counts towards the height.

Try something like (height/20 - 4)